# Override library elements class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

I am using tabs from element UI in one of the project. Please have a look to link : 
https://jsfiddle.net/x3ybe784/

here, there is a library generated div with class **el-tabs__content**

```
el-tabs__content {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

I have to override `overflow: hidden`; to `overflow: visiable`;

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put

```
el-tabs__content {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Later in the page and it will override the style. So include it in a file after your libraries css.